# Ansible configuration: Paths not relative to ansible.cfg?

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

#### Overall context

I am trying to split all the security-wise sensitive information out of the revision control tree of a set of ansible playbooks and roles. The sensitive information are
things like actual IP addresses of our hardware, the become usernames, initial user
passwords and such. These variables somehow naturally show up in two places. One is
`ansible.cfg` and another the `group_vars` directory at the root of the ansible repo.

#### ansible.cfg

I have moved ansible config file to a separate directory. It contains *relative paths* to a vault password, as well as several *vault_id* files. I run my playbooks like this,

```bash
ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/path/to/ansible.cfg ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
```

My expectation was that ansible will try to locate paths to secrets (contained in the `ansible.cfg` .. such as `vault_identity_list`) relative to `ansible.cfg`. The reasoning is based on a paragraph from [Ansible 2.4 porting guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.4.html).

> All relative paths defined are relative to the ansible.cfg file itself. Previously they varied by setting. The new behavior should be more predictable.

This is actually not the case and the password files are still going to be looked for relative to the directory where playbook has been executed from (or, maybe the directory containing the playbook, not sure about this) and not relative to `ansible.cfg`

I was wondering if one can *make* Ansible look up password files somewhere else (ie using an environment variable).

My current solution is to soft-link the needed files into the directory of the playbook.

Ansible version: `2.10`

Answer (score 1):

What you are misreading in the porting guide is that it is implicite that in

> All relative paths defined are relative to the ansible.cfg file itself.

They meant

> All relative paths defined *[in the ansible.cfg file]* are relative to the ansible.cfg file itself.

You can also understand this clearer when the porting guide sentence is in context, [in the actual configuration file documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#relative-paths-for-configuration).

---

If you want to fetch a file relative to the location of the configuration file used, you could us the [special variable `ansible_config_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html), then get its directory with the [`dirname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) filter.

So, for example:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_config_file | dirname }}/foo.txt"
```

When run with

```bash
ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/path/to/ansible.cfg ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

Will yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: /path/to/foo.txt
```

Comment: But, "All relative paths defined [in the ansible.cfg file] are relative to the ansible.cfg file itself." is precisely what I want. I have a setting like `vault_identity_list = label@secretdir/label.txt`. In my experience, ansible does not look for secretdir/label.txt relative to ansible.cfg (in the subdir `secretdir` of ansible.cfg's dir), but there where i executed the play. Just clarified this in my question.